# Position fixed element within fixed element relative to page

Tags: html, css

I've got a fixed container which is vertically and horizontally centred on the page, and an element within that container. Ideally I would like to have this element positioned in the very top left of the window, however I'm struggling to make it work.

This JS Bin illustrates the problem.

https://jsbin.com/nodonatifo/edit?html,css,output

Initially I thought I would just be able to do something like this on the element.

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #55ffdd;
  /* Center on page */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#element-actual {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element-actual"></div>
</div>
```

However that just fixes the element in the top left corner of the parent container, rather than the window.

Is this possible with my current styles?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: If you're using `position:fixed`...why does it need to be a child?

Comment: It's actually a modal component within an Ember app, and so has to work wherever this component is placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gaurav Aggarwal already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33943940/2680216), the fixed element will still be relative to the parent's transformed positioning. If you want the container element to be dynamically positioned (even if it has unknown dimensions), then you could use the following approach and avoid using `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` for vertical/horizontal centering.

This method essentially positions the container element to fill the height/width of the window element with `top: 0`/`right: 0`/`bottom: 0`/`left: 0`, and then centers it vertically/horizontally using `margin: auto`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cu48w3r/)

```css
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #55ffdd;
}
#element-actual {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="element-actual"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but that will make the `#container` to be shown on full height as per the window

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Are you sure about that? That doesn't seem to happen in the example I provided.

Comment: yes i am sure because in the example you provided height is still known. Try with removing `height` property then you will see the problem

Comment: This is what I needed, cheers Josh. Nice little trick with the `top:0` etc and `margin: auto`too.

Answer (score 4):

```
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #55ffdd;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}
```

If you use `translate` property then its children div will place relatively to the parent div only even when it is `position:fixed` so you can use the above code to place `#container` in center and you red div will be placed relatively to the window not the parent div :)

Comment: Thanks, that's great, and does solve the issue. Is it possible to achieve the same vertical centering if the container is an unknown height, without breaking the fixed element's positioning?

Comment: No, because that will be only possible with your previous code `translate` which doesn't suits this scenario so for height should be known for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, add this to the child:

```
position: sticky;
```